# How to get thumbnail for Vimeo video using new API

Tags: php, wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to output the image thumbnail for Vimeo videos embedded on my wordpress site using PHP. The Vimeo videos have domain level privacy.

It looks like Vimeo have updated their API, as I've tried the suggestions in other answers posted here a few years ago, but none of these are working. I've looked through their new API and can't seem to get my head around it.

Specifically, I've tried a few variations of this:

```
<?php
$imgid = 6271487;
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$imgid.php"));
echo $hash[0]['thumbnail_medium'];
```

This always retruns a form of fatal error.

Any help on the best way of achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post output of `print_r($hash);`?

Comment: are you sure the api is not on HTTPS? try https

Comment: Here's the output of print_r($hash) with https  " file_get_contents(https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/276827365.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in ..."

Comment: did you try https? instead of http?

Comment: "This always retruns a form of fatal error. " What form?

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, I contacted Vimeo and they supplied the below which seems to work perfectly:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/VIDEO_ID",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Referer: REFERER_URL"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A few things: First, that API with the path `/api/v2/video/`, has been deprecated and replaced by the "new" API, released a couple of years back.

Second: The old API only supported the extensions `.xml` and `.json`, returning a response in those respective formats; `.php` is not supported by the old API.

To get a video's thumbnail, you'll need to use [the new API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video), or if the video is public and embeddable use [oEmbed](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos). Using the Vimeo PHP library, a request to get a video's metadata would look like this:

```
$videoId = '6271487';
$response = $client->request('/videos/'+$videoId+'/pictures', array(), 'GET');
print_r($response);
```

An oEmbed request would look like this (expressed as curl, note that Vimeo's oEmbed implementation will only return `json` or `xml`):

```
curl -X GET 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/6271487'
```

Good luck!

Comment: This API is still working it's not recommended for use but it certainly still works just fine, if all your trying to get is a thumbnail for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the thumbnail image for default size from the vimeo video. Then you just pass your video ID to here.

```
https://vumbnail.com/YOUR_VIDEO_ID.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an access token in the headers for an API request. You'll also need to use the correct API urls.

Start here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start

Comment: Not really, the oembed is public

Comment: Well, he asked for an API solution. Neg if you want.